# How to grant multiple users privileges; MySQL

Tags: mysql, dns

I have the following code:

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE ON db1.*
TO ‘user’@example.com;
```

I am a beginner in mySQL, I was wondering if there is a method in which I can specific the privileges for every user in this domain network without having to type the above code for each user? %wildcard?

Also is there any method such as using a table where I can manage all the privileges of said users

Comment: do you have a table with a list of all the users?

Comment: If I was to do so, do I simply insert the necessary columns and named them e.g. Insert_priv? and update the values to Yes? or is it Y?

Answer (score 13):

The GRANT syntax allows you to specify multiple users in a single query. You can't do it with a wildcard, but if you already have the list you can do this:

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE ON db1.*
TO 'user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4', 'user5', 'user6';
```

Answer (score 2):

As documented under [`GRANT` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/grant.html):

> #### Account Names and Passwords
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> You can specify wildcards in the host name. For example, `user_name@'%.example.com'` applies to *`user_name`* for any host in the `example.com` domain, and `user_name@'192.168.1.%'` applies to *`user_name`* for any host in the `192.168.1` class C subnet.
>
> The simple form user_name is a synonym for user_name@'%'.
>
> *MySQL does not support wildcards in user names.*

However, you can also manage account permissions by manipulating the [MySQL grant tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant-table-structure.html) directly (and then executing [`FLUSH PRIVILEGES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/flush.html)).

Answer (score 0):

You could write a PHP script to grant each person access. However I would not recommend creating new MySQL accounts for each user. Your application should deal with all of the read / write permissions

Comment: is there a method without using phpmyAdmin or php script? I only want to use the commands available to me through mysql

Comment: Unless you already have the names stored in another table.